# How to show line of an error in logs in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

There is an error printed to console but I don't know in which line of the code. I am using Intellij Idea to develop a Node.js application but I tested my code in Visual Studio Code editor as well to see the line of error but didn't work.

Current log;

**An error occurred : Cannot read property 'language' of undefined**

I expect to see something like;

**An error occurred : Cannot read property 'language' of undefined (TestController.js line:127)**

Is it possible to have such easiness?

Comment: the line number is normally shown on the next line of stack trace, like: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous> (E:\projects\express\app.js:39:34)`. Anyway, it doesn't seem to be possible to configure this...